# Testing server indexed in Google

Tags: seo, google-search-console, htaccess, search-engine-indexing, googlebot

Assume our website domain to be www.example.com.

And we have created a separate testing environment within our main domain:
Say : www.project.example.com.

So we have two versions within our main domain server. One is for testing and building new updates and the other one is live server.

I see www.projects.example.com indexed in Google which is our testing server.

Is there any option to restrict this testing environment from being indexed in Google?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add a robots.txt file that disallows either all robots or just the Google bot.